# .htaccess remove codeigniter url parameter can't working

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I want to try remove url parameter like this example:
http:// mypoject/controller/method/?page=1 =>http:// mypoject/controller/method/page/1/ but my .htaccess can't perfect execute

```js
 RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|swf|uploads|js|css|assets|robots\.txt|$)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^/home/{controller}/{method}/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$ /home/{controller}/{method}/?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

set request route

```
$route['{default_controller}/{default_method}/([a-zA-z0-9]+)'] = "{original_controller}/{original_method}/$1";
```

my demo page  http://www.atline.com.tw/home/welcome/test/66